# Calculating average time for a memory access

Tags: performance, memory, computer-science, cpu-architecture, cpu-cache

I find it hard to understand the differences between the local and global miss rate and how to calculate the average time for a memory access and would just like to give an example of a problem that I have tried to solve. I would appreciate if someone could tell me if I'm on the right track, or if I'm wrong what I have missed.

Consider the following multilevel cache hierarchy with their seek times and miss rates:

- L1-cache, 0.5 ns, 20%
- L2-cache, 1.8 ns, 5%
- L3-cache, 4.2 ns, 1.5%
- Main memory, 70 ns, 0%

In this case, the seek times given refer to the total time it takes to both check whether the requested data is available on the current level of hierarchy, and transmit the data to the level above (or to the CPU). This is the same as hit time, right?
The miss rates given are local. And as I have understood, the a miss rate of one level needs to be multiplied with the miss rates of all previous levels in order to be correct for that level.

Lets say if we have 1000 memory accesses, in L1 20% of them will miss. So 20% of them will go to L2, there 5% of these will miss. So from 1000 memory accesses 1000 * 20% * 5% will get there.
Now, as far as I know... and please correct me if I am wrong, the above miss rates are local, but their product is the global missrate for each corresponding level. This means the global miss rate would be 0,2*0,05 = 1% for L2.

Now, I may be very wrong with this calculation but this is how I think:

```
AMAT (Average Memory Access Time) = Hit time + Miss rate * Miss penalty

AMAT = 0.5 + 0.2 * (1.8 + 0.2 * 0.05 * (4.2 + 0.2 * 0.05 * 0.015 * 70))
```

After calculating this I get AMAT = 0.868421 ns

Am I doing this correctly?

Comment: Maybe define `AMAT`...

Comment: @MarkSetchell Average Memory Access Time (AMAT) is a way of measuring the performance of a memory-hierarchy configuration. It takes into account that misses on different levels of the hierarchy affects the overall system performance differently.

Comment: I'm sure you are misinterpreting cache miss rate. 1.5% L3-cache misses means 1.5% of _all_ memory accesses miss.

Comment: @gnasher729 thanks for your reply. Are you sure that what you suggest applies to this example, where Miss rates are stated to be local?

Answer (score 6):

Now it has become clear to me what exactly global and local miss rate is, and thus I realize I made a mistake in my calculation.

Before, the calculation looked like this:

AMAT = 0.5 + 0.2 * (1.8 + 0.2 * 0.05 * (4.2 + 0.2 * 0.05 * 0.015 * 70)) = 0.868421 ns

This means that the local miss rate of, for example, L1, affects the contributions of miss penalty for each further away in the hierarchy, too many times.. when it already has been accounted for in a previous stage.

The correct solution should be:

AMAT = 0.5 + 0.2 * (1.8 + 0.05 * (4.2 + 0.015 * 70)) = 0.9125 ns

So, recursively we can define:

AMAT = L1 Hit time + L1 Miss rate * L1 Miss penalty

L1 Miss penalty = L2 Hit time + L2 Miss rate * L2 Miss penalty

L2 Miss penalty = L3 Hit time + L3 Miss rate * L3 Miss penalty

L3 Miss penalty = Main memory hit time

Comment: Nice answer, adding the "recursive" formulas makes it more easy to understand this kind of things!

Comment: Sometimes a system will specify L3 hit time = whatever as the *total* time for a memory access that ultimately results in an L2 miss / L3 hit.  So that 4.2 ns wouldn't be the penalty on top of checking L1 and then L2, instead the total penalty.  In that case it would already include L1 time, so to avoid double-counting L1 time you'd want `L1hit_time * L1hitrate + L1 miss average * (1 - L1hitrate)`